# Xml parsing in android

Tags: android

In android app, i want to send a php requeset, and am expecting a response in the form of xml, from the server.

Can anybody provide pointers in this case.

Comment: can you provide us with what you have done already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XmlPullParser bundled with android to parse the response. To get the parser instance use this snippet:

```
XmlPullParser pullParser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
pullParser.setInput(...); //Set input source with response you parsing.
```

Comment: You'd mis-spelled XmlPullParser as XmlPullarser, fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 methods for parsing XMl in android. See [working with xml in android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Xstream is your friend http://x-stream.github.io/

XStream is a simple library to serialize objects to XML and back again.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try out my XmlParsing library.

https://github.com/frenchie4111/XmlParser

Let me know if you have any problems with it.